# Binding with multiple lower layered objects into a listview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a workout app for college and I'm struggling with returning multiple objects into a ListView without hardcoding their position in the collection as shown in my data template code below.

XAML Data Template Code:

```
<ContentView.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkoutTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Workout.WorkoutExercises[0].Exercise.ExerciseName}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Workout.WorkoutExercises[0].Exercise.ExerciseSetExercises[0].ExerciseSet.SetNumber}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Workout.WorkoutExercises[0].Exercise.ExerciseSetExercises[0].ExerciseSet.RepsCompleted}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Workout.WorkoutExercises[0].Exercise.ExerciseSetExercises[0].ExerciseSet.WeightLifted}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

XAML ListView:

```
<ContentView.Content>
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
        <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClientWorkout}" x:Name="ClientWorkoutsDetailsListView" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WorkoutTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

The SelectedClientWorkout binding has multiple layers as shown in the data template. Its Workout object has a collection of WorkoutExercises, each has an Exercise object, each of them have collections of ExerciseSetExercises, each having an ExerciseSet object. This is the snippet of JSON thats returned into the object so you can see the structure of the data:

```
[
{
    "cWorkoutId": "1",
    "workout": {
        "workoutId": "1",
        "workoutName": "Chest",
        "workoutExercises": [
            {
                "weId": "1",
                "wId": "1",
                "eId": "1",
                "exercise": {
                    "eId": "1",
                    "exerciseName": "Bench Press",
                    "exerciseSetExercises": [
                        {
                            "eSetId": "1",
                            "eId": "1",
                            "cwId": "1",
                            "exerciseSet": {
                                "exerciseSetId": "1",
                                "setNumber": 1,
                                "repsCompleted": 15,
                                "weightLifted": 60.0,
```

I'd like to bind the label text without specifying the position like this:
**Text="{Binding Workout.WorkoutExercises.Exercise.ExerciseName}"**
and have the listview populate all the Exercise names etc. that are in the workout but nothing is returning for me when i do this. Could someone point out where i am going wrong please?

Comment: to start with, it seems like your ItemsSource should be `Workout.WorkoutExercises`, so that each row is an instance of a `WorkoutExercise`

Comment: as next u can select only the desired properties in DTO model  ...

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried changing my ListViews ItemSource to "{Binding SelectedClientWorkout.Workout.WorkoutExercises}" and the labels Text binding to "{Binding Exercise.ExerciseName}" but this caused the data to disappear. SelectedClientWorkout is an object created in the View Model

Comment: `SelectedClientWorkout = WorkoutExercises (list of object Exercise) -> ExerciseSetExercises (list of object ExerciseSet)` is this correct? if this is correct then you wanted to show _SelectedClientWorkout.WorkoutExercises[0].ExerciseSetExercises_ in your UI? Or you wanted to show [All WorkoutExercises's ExerciseSetExercises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQnkh8GpUQU) in your UI.

Comment: Thank you Ranjit, you are pretty much right, there is a workout object in there as well though: **SelectedClientWorkout = Workout -> WorkoutExercises (list of object Exercise) -> ExerciseSetExercises (list of object ExerciseSet)**.   The SelectedClientWorkout get its data from an API call, e.g. **SelectedClientWorkout = (await dataService.GetCWAsync(selectedCW.id)).ToObservableCollection();**  
I assume I need to modify this object in the ViewModel before I can use this in the xaml page?

Comment: If you want to show all ExerciseSet from each root node. Then flatten the complete list into ExerciseSet and for ExerciseName create one more property in ExerciseSet. Then you can bind collection of ExerciseSet into listview. For flattening list you can go though SelectMany link query.

Comment: Thank you again all, I've managed to resolve the problem by creating a new flattened API and model.

Comment: @PhillipWatkins - It would be great if you add an *answer* showing how you solved it. (You can answer your own question!) This may help others with the same problem. Then after 48 hours, you can accept your own answer.